# Google App Engine: keep state of an object between HTTP-requests (Java)

Tags: google-app-engine

User makes HTTP-request to the server. This request is processed with an object of some class, let's call it "Processor". Then the same user in two minutes makes another HTTP request. And I want it to be processed with the same instance of Processor as the first one. So basically I want to keep the state of some object among several requests.

I know that I can save it each time to the datastore and then load back, but this approach seems to be very slow. Is there a way to store objects in some RAM place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If memcache isn't enough, you could use backends to maintain state. Use a resident backend (or a set of them) and route incoming requests from the frontend to the backend machine that has the state.

Docs: [Python](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/overview) [Java](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/backends/overview)

Comment: Actually I use Google AppEngine as the back-end in my system :)

Comment: By backend I mean an App Engine backend, which lets you maintain state between requests and lets you directly address each server.

Comment: I see now, you are right, AppEngine Backend technology fits my purposes best: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/backends/ Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

How about using [memcache](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/memcache/)?

You can't ensure that consecutive requests to your app will go to the same instance, but memcache can help reduce or eliminate the overhead of accessing the datastore for each request.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are describing is a *session*.

I am not sure which language runtime and web framework you are using, but it is sure to include support for a sessions.  (If you are using Java you will need to [enable it](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#Java_appengine_web_xml_Enabling_sessions).)

The standard session mechanism puts a small ID in a cookie that is stored in the user's browser. On every request, each of which could be go to a different application server, this ID is used as a key to read and write persistent information from the data store.

If the datastore accesses are too slow for you I would suggest not using memcache for this session storage, because memcache is by design *unreliable*, so the user's session information could disappear at any time, which would be a bad experience for them.

If the amount of data you want to store is less than about a few kilobytes, then I recommend doing what Play Framework does, which is to encrypt your session data and store it directly in a cookie stored in the user's browser.  This is fast and truly stateless.

If you have more data than can be stored in a cookie, and you don't want to use the data store, you could could use JavaScript local storage on the browser, and use AJAX calls to communicate with the server.  (If you want to support older browsers you may need to use the [jStorage](http://www.jstorage.info/) wrapper library.)